# Using Google Datastore in Java (Spring MVC) foreach in JSTL

Tags: java, spring-mvc, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I wanna send Datastore from java to jsp page and using JSTL to foreach this data
When i run this code it's return

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /. Reason:

Could not find property email in class com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity
```

Here my code
HomeController.java

```
    Key customerKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Customer", "your name");
    Entity customer = new Entity("Customer", customerKey);
    customer.setProperty("name", "Test");
    customer.setProperty("email", "test@gmail.com");

    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    datastore.put(customer); //save it
    Query query = new Query("Customer").addSort("name", Query.SortDirection.DESCENDING);
    List<Entity> customers = datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(10));
    model.addAttribute("customerList", customers);
    return "home";
```

home.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
    <table>
<c:forEach items="${customerList}" var="user">
    <tr>
        <td> <c:out value="${user.email}"/> </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Thank you for every answer

Comment: Instead of setting values using property create POJO class and initialize name and email attributes inside it and generate getters and setters for it.
and pass that POJO with model attribute.
Now you can use your your POJO in JSTl

Comment: Yes, use a POJO, you want want to try object mapping frameworks for GAE like Twist: http://git.io/OGKDBQ